# Interpreting categorical variable importance in logistic regression

Tags: r, variables, logistic-regression, r-caret

I'm using the caret package in R to build a logistic regression model for binary classification and one of my predictors is a categorical variable with 4 levels. Below is my code.

```
> mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
> mydata$admit <- factor(mydata$admit)
> mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   400 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ admit: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ gre  : int  380 660 800 640 520 760 560 400 540 700 ...
 $ gpa  : num  3.61 3.67 4 3.19 2.93 3 2.98 3.08 3.39 3.92 ...
 $ rank : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 3 3 1 4 4 2 1 2 3 2 ...
> mymod <- train(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data=mydata, method="glm", family="binomial")
> summary(mymod)$coeff
                Estimate  Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -3.989979073 1.139950936 -3.500132 0.0004650273
gre          0.002264426 0.001093998  2.069864 0.0384651284
gpa          0.804037549 0.331819298  2.423119 0.0153878974
rank2       -0.675442928 0.316489661 -2.134171 0.0328288188
rank3       -1.340203916 0.345306418 -3.881202 0.0001039415
rank4       -1.551463677 0.417831633 -3.713131 0.0002047107
> varImp(mymod)
glm variable importance

      Overall
rank3  100.00
rank4   90.72
gpa     19.50
rank2    3.55
gre      0.00
```

My question is, how do I interpret `varImp` for the model, especially with respect to rank? Since R has assumed rank1 to the be baseline class, does `varImp` being highest for rank3 mean that admit is most different for the observations when rank is 3 in comparison with when rank is 1? If this is the case, it doesn't seem to have the same story as the coefficients of the model because rank4 has a steeper slope than rank3, even though it is of lower importance according to `varImp`.

Comment: This isn't a coding question. Should be migrated to CV.com. It appears to me that you don't even understand the interpretation of regression coefficients. My additional statistical concern is that coefficients of categorical variables should not be be considered as "slopes".

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation to `caret::varImp`? It's self-explanatory. Though I will state that there's absolutely no reason to use variable importance metrics for a GLM